# Display Data from sqLite DB into different TextViews

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, textview

Now i have a working sqLite Database, a working Database search on a working ListView that showing the data that was searched.

But i down't know how to display the Data from the result from the database into different TextViews.

I have 3 activities for the database thing:

Search Activity -> ListView Activity -> Details Activity

How can i put the selected item from the ListView into a new activity and fill the TextViews with the Data from the database?

I hope that you can understand what i mean. Write in english isn't my best skill ;)

Here the Code:

**ShowStations.java**

```
package san.tal.tfapp.Bahnhoefe;


import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;


import san.tal.tfapp.R;

public class ShowStations extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_stations2);


    //TextViews werden eingebunden
    TextView station_ckanal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show_ckanal);
    TextView station_fdl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show_fdl);
    TextView station_lastrecke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show_laStrecke);
    TextView station_linie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show_linie);
    TextView station_art = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_art);

    }




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_show_stations, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

**ShowStationList.java**

```
  package san.tal.tfapp.Bahnhoefe;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.AdapterView;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.List;

  import san.tal.tfapp.Database.DatabaseSourceStations;
  import san.tal.tfapp.Models.Station;
  import san.tal.tfapp.R;
  import san.tal.tfapp.showPhoneNumbers;

  public class ShowStationList extends ActionBarActivity {

  public static final String KEY_SEARCH_STRING = "key_search_string";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_station_list);

    final ListView stationsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    stationsListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String searchString = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_SEARCH_STRING);
    if (searchString != null) {

        final List<Station> stations = queryList(searchString);
        String[] namesArray = Station.getNamesArray(stations);
        stationsListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, namesArray));

        stationsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                stations.get(position).getId();
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Kein Suchbegriff eingegeben", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}

private List<Station> queryList(String searchString) {

    DatabaseSourceStations databaseSourceStations = new DatabaseSourceStations(this);
    try {
        databaseSourceStations.open();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Datenbank konnte nicht kopiert werden!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    List<Station> stationList = databaseSourceStations.searchStation(searchString);
    databaseSourceStations.close();

    return stationList;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_show_station_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
 }
```

**DatabaseSourceStations.java**

```
package san.tal.tfapp.Database;

import android.content.ContentValues; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import san.tal.tfapp.Models.Station;

/**
 * Created by Talsan on 17.02.2015.
 */
public class DatabaseSourceStations {

SQLiteDatabase database;
DatabaseHelperStations databaseHelperStations;

public DatabaseSourceStations(Context context) {
    databaseHelperStations = DatabaseHelperStations.instance(context);
}

public void open() throws IOException {
    database = databaseHelperStations.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    database.close();
}

public long addStation(Station station) {

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_NAME, station.getName());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_RIL100, station.getRil100());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_CKANAL, station.getCkanal());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_LASTRECKE, station.getLastrecke());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_LINIE,  station.getLinie());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_FDL, station.getFdl());
    contentValues.put(DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_ART, station.getArt());

    return database.insert(DatabaseHelperStations.DB_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public void addStations(List<Station> stationList) {

    for (Station station : stationList) {
        addStation(station);
    }
}

public List<Station> getEverything() {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelperStations.DB_NAME + ";";

    return cursorToStationList(database.rawQuery(query, null));
}

public List<Station> searchStation(String searchString) {

    String optimizedQuery = "%" + searchString + "%";

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelperStations.DB_NAME +
            " WHERE " + DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_NAME + " LIKE '" +  optimizedQuery + "' OR " + DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_RIL100 + " LIKE '" +  optimizedQuery + "';";

    return cursorToStationList(database.rawQuery(query, null));
}

public List<Station> cursorToStationList(Cursor cursor) {

    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    List<Station> stations = new ArrayList<>();

    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        stations.add(cursorToStation(cursor));

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    return stations;
}

    public Station cursorToStation(Cursor cursor) {
    Station station = new Station();
    station.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
    station.setName(cursor.getString(1));
    station.setRil100(cursor.getString(2));
    station.setCkanal(cursor.getString(3));
    station.setLastrecke(cursor.getInt(4));
    station.setLinie(cursor.getString(5));
    station.setFdl(cursor.getString(6));
    station.setArt(cursor.getString(7));
    return station;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `OnItemClickListener` of your `ListView`, you can create the intent to save the station ID and then start your new activity. I assume that `ShowStations` is the `Details Activity`.

Edit the `stationsListView` `OnItemClickListener` in your `ShowStationList` with this:

```
stationsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        int stationID = stations.get(position).getId();

        Intent intent = new Intent(ShowStations.this, ShowStationList.class);
        intent.putExtra("station_id",stationID);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In your `ShowStations` class, you would need to call `getIntent()` to get the ID that was saved in the intent and retrieve the details from the database using the ID.

```
public class ShowStations extends ActionBarActivity {

    DatabaseSourceStations databaseSourceStations;
    Station aStation = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_stations2);

        int stationID = getIntent().getIntExtra("station_id", 0);

        databaseSourceStations = new DatabaseSourceStations(this);
        try {
            databaseSourceStations.open();

            // retrieve the station details from the database here, 
            // I assume you have a method called 'getSingleStationDetails' 
            // that returns a single station with the specified ID

            aStation = databaseSourceStations.getSingleStationDetails(stationID);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        databaseSourceStations.close();

        //TextViews werden eingebunden
        TextView station_ckanal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show_ckanal);
        TextView station_fdl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show_fdl);
        TextView station_lastrecke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show_laStrecke);
        TextView station_linie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_show_linie);
        TextView station_art = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_art);

        if (aStation != null) {
            // set the details of the text views here
        }

    }

    ...
```

Let me know if this helps.

**Edit**

In your `DatabaseSourceStations` class, the `getSingleStationDetails` method should look like this :

```
public Station getSingleStationDetails(int stationID) {
    // I assume that your station's table name is DatabaseHelperStations.TABLE_NAME
    // and that it has a column named DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_ID 

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelperStations.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_ID + " = " + stationID + ";";

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    Station aStation = null;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        aStation = cursorToStation(cursor);
    }

    cursor.close();

    return aStation;
}
```

Comment: Ok looks great. But i get errors: 1. at new Intent(ShowStations.this) "is not an enclosing class". And at ShowStations at DatabaseSourceStations = new DatabaseSourceStations at the first DatabaseSourceStations "Expression expected". And the 3rd on .open() and .close() EDIT: Ok only the 1st error

Comment: "I assume you have a method called 'getSingleStationDetails' " And no... i only have a Basic form Android Studio created method for it.

Comment: Ok with "intent = new Intent(ShowStationList.this, ShowStations.class);" i get no error. is this ok?

Comment: @Talsan If you don't have the method, you should create it yourself. Do you still have errors?

Comment: Yes atif (aStation != null) { and at the other aStation. The First aStation in the Code is a "Not in use"  warning.

Comment: @Talsan Did you add `getSingleStationDetails`  to your database helper class?

Comment: Yes but only with one return null;

Comment: Is it ok that the column is _id?. And i will try when i today evening at home

Comment: Ok i had add your Code in my "DatabaseHelperStations.java" class. Now the 1st aStation in "ShowStations.java" is grey and the 2nd is red (error: Cannot resolve Symbol). and i had changed your line to " public static Station getSingleStationDetails(int stationID) {" cause without the "static" i had an error.

Comment: @Talsan Put the `getSingleStationDetails` method in your `DatabaseSourceStations` class instead. I updated my answer to fix the error.

Comment: Ok no errors so far. But i had changed your SELECT "DatabaseHelperStations.COLUMN_ID + " = " + stationID" The "+" after COLUMN_ID is new. Do you forget it? Cause withaut the + i get an error.

Comment: "if (aStation != null) {
            station_ckanal.setText(aStation.getCkanal());
        }" Is this the right code?

Comment: @Talsan Yes that's the right code. And I forgot to add the `+` since I didn't test it. I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like get get all the corresponding fields in onItemClick function
put the information into Bundle something like this
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

```
bundle.pustString(key,value);
```

Then start the activity through intent with the information

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.pustExtra(key,bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in the details activity get the Bundle from intent something like this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
```

Iterate through bundle to get the individual values so that you can set them in TextViews by calling

```
textView.setText(bundle.getString(key));
```